# How to query SAP Bex using batch files

Tags: batch-file, automation, sap-bw

I'm wanting to automate and schedule some SAP queries. 
The queries themselves are fairly standard and the only variable will be the date, I want it to pull the latest 52 weeks, every Sunday.

I think the best way to do this is to set up a batch file and schedule those but I have no idea how to write a batch file that interacts with SAP BEX.

It just needs to 
Open the query that I have set up
Refresh it with the new date range
Save and close it in the same location

Sounds easy but I don't know where to start. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the concept of 'Information Broadcasting' where you can send reports using e-mail, store them in the Portal etc.

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/a5/359840dfa5a160e10000000a1550b0/content.htm